# string parameter in controller is null when using webclient

Tags: c#, webclient, asp.net-apicontroller, uploadstring

When I use WebClient to call a function in a controller

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    client.BaseAddress = "http://localhost/";
    client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");
    client.UploadString("api/test", HttpMethod.Put.ToString(), stringParameter);
}
```

I called the function in controller successfully but the "stringParameter" in controller is empty like the following code:

```
[Route("api/test")]
[HttpPut]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Test([FromBody] string stringParameter)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // the flow goes here
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }
    // ...
}
```

I would like to know where is the mistake(s) I made and how to fix the problem(s). Thank you very much.
Remark: "stringParameter" is fine if it is numeric such as "123" but not work if it is "A123" or "B123".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're setting content type to "application/json" you should be sending a valid JSON value rather then raw string. A number is JSON and in plain text is the same, so that's why it works.

Try serializing the text to JSON before sending:
`JsonConvert.ToString(stringParameter);`
(I'm using Newtonsoft.Json nuget package here)

Alternatively you can try to use content type `text/plain`, but I'm not sure if your web api is configured to handle that by default.

Comment: It is work with using JsonConvert.ToString(stringParameter); Thanks for your help